# Word for a woman who can be mistaken as a transexual.

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

Is there a noun or adjective for this? Whether slang or a formal word.

Comment: No, there is no specific word for this.

Comment: Nothing specific comes to mind but she's [manly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/manly) I suppose? The [-ly](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=-ly&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on) suffix indicates likeness or resemblance so it doesn't have to (and can't) apply to the original thing and being mistaken for a transsexual suggests masculine traits. That is not to say that I'd recommend calling women who don't self-identify as transsexuals manly though ... It just seems applicable.

Comment: What's wrong with: "*I thought she was a trans/gender/sexual/woman"? OR "*She looks like a transsexual/gender/woman.*"

Comment: Are you referring to a woman who changed her sex from a man or a man who changed it from a woman? And in what context do you need to use this word? The following is the rule of this community. **Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered**. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Do you mean *transsexual* or *transgender*?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for ***[androgynous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/androgynous)***

**androgynous (adj.)**

> having an ambiguous sexual identity.

[Dictionary.com]

*Usage* :

> I mistook Alice for a transexual due to her **androgynous** looks.

Comment: "A transgender"? I believe using transgender as a noun in this way is considered offensive (see Wiktionary).

Comment: @mikeagg - 
It is mentioned that it is sometimes considered offensive. But it is unclear under what circumstances will it be considered offensive. I live in India, and we have "Transgender Rights"/ "Transgender laws"/"Self Help Groups for Transgenders".. and so on. However, I take your point. I have edited my answer to be in-line with OP's usage.